# Digital Signature for Acrobat

Tags: java, itext, keystore, acrobat, jks

Trying to get an authenticated digital signature onto a PDF in Acrobat, by using iText. The way we want to grab someone digital signature is through there cert, which in our case we would be getting the user cert through their CAC's. Having issue with the ks.load() where I am getting an error: "Invalid key store format". Wonder if it is even possible without using any cmd? Would prefer a solution that involves Java.

```
    String KEYSTORE = ReadConfig.get("WebRoot")+"mods/Reports/sources/t_cert.jks";
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), null);
    String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, null);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by CAC? That TLA had multiple meanings...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You need to improve your question a bit: (1) Your sentences are not clear: "signature onto a PDF in acrobat by using iText" I guess you want to add a digital signature to a PDF using iText and later it should be verifyable using Acrobat? (2) Introduce your abbreviations first: CAC=Certificate Authority? CMD=Command line? (3) indicate with a comment which lines fails ...

Comment: So now to your question: (1) Yes it is possible in plain java (2) Maybe your keystore is not JKS but PKCS12? Did you try to open your keystore using keystore explorer? Is that possible? Maybe you need a keystore password?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to take a user digital signature from there cert and have it populate onto a PDF, which would be in Acrobat. Yes, CAC=Certificate and CMD = Command Line.

Comment: It fails on line 5 when trying to do to the ks.load()

Comment: No, I have not tried opening my keystore using keystore explorer, how would I go about in opening my keystore using keystore explorer?

Comment: Used KeyStore Explorer and that fixed my issue of Invalid key store format. Thank you all for your help!